# Pom splitting, transitive dependency profile

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a pom.xml file which is too long, 900+ lines.

Have a solution for pom splitting ?

And if it's possible (or not) to add dependency on my project and use dependency profile on my project ?

Example :

Project1 with profile bindapp and
Project2 with Project1 dependency with profile

cd Project2 && mvn install -Pbindapp ?

I test it, but it's not found

Comment: Do you have two projects or single project...can give more details how your project setup looks like and why your pom is so long? Many dependencies? Or what?

Comment: What is the reason that the POM is so long? Maybe you need a parent POM for the standard configuration of your company or team?

Comment: @khmarbaise have many dependencies and for example have many executions on plugins for generated xml models (jaxb2), api generations (many api.yml from open api generator) etc ...

Comment: @JFabianMeier it's specific to my project

Comment: My own team mate prupose me to split profile in another file in Project2, and unpack this file on my Project1, but i don't think it's the better way to do this.

Comment: EDIT : My own team mate prupose me to split profile in another file in Project1, and unpack this file on my Project2, but i don't think it's the better way to do this.

Comment: You should not define a second project just to split up the POM. But if you have the impression that your project does "too much", it may be worth splitting up the project into modules.

Comment: The modules way is the right way...for example one with jaxb2 part... of course the root of your projects should define the versions for the plugins etc. and via dependencyManagement define the versions for all dependencies but make separation of concerns in poms as well as doing in code...many executions is exactly such an indicator...